# Keeping a users selection maintained through paging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down selection box that appends a string to the URL, this then sorts a catalog based on the post back with the URL string change. So for example the URL might look like this:

http://example.com/Products/Catalogue/tabid/102/page/2/pagemid/554/Catalogue.aspx

if I made a selection of the second value which is a sort by 'Title A-Z' which will append ?orderby=2 which will make the URL like:

http://example.com/Products/Catalogue/tabid/102/page/2/pagemid/554/Catalogue.aspx?orderby=2

On a page you can do this but as soon as you select a new page from the catalog it forgets the selection, so the URL might change the page like ...page/3/... example:

http://example.com/Products/Catalogue/tabid/102/page/3/pagemid/554/Catalogue.aspx

Notice the ?orderby=2 is missing? the question is how do I get this to be a persitant selection through javascript or Jquery?

Here is the current script that is doing what you see above, however does not maintain the selection on the paging refresh.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 (function($) {
     $.QueryString = (function(a) {
         if (a == "") return {};
         var b = {};
         for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
         {
             var p=a[i].split('=');
             if (p.length != 2) continue;
             b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
         }
         return b;
     })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
 })(jQuery);
 var qstr=$.QueryString["orderby"];
 //alert(qstr);
 //$("#Selection").prop("selectedIndex", qstr); 
 </script>

  <select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
    <option  id=1 value="">Sort by</option>
    <option  id=2 value="?orderby=1">Code</option>
    <option  id=3 value="?orderby=2">Title A-Z</option>
    <option  id=4 value="?orderby=3">Title Z-A</option>
    <option  id=5 value="?orderby=4">Brand</option>
    <option  id=6 value="?orderby=5">Lowest price</option>
    <option  id=7 value="?orderby=6">Highest price</option>
    <option  id=8 value="?orderby=7">Lowest Quantity</option>
    <option  id=9 value="?orderby=8">Highest Quantity</option>
  </select>

 <script>$("#Selection").prop("selectedIndex", qstr); </script>
```

Help help on this would be awesome, I have no idea where to even begin...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: If you want to persist values throughout the session then it would be advisable to use session cookies at client side where you can store this information page wise

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the Ordering Index across requests and as the page loads check the ordering index and sort accordingly.

Your second URL should be:
example.com/Products/Catalogue/tabid/102/page/3/pagemid/554/Catalogue.aspx?orderby=2

Comment: Thats just it it does not seem to check this and I am wondering how I can get javascript to do this?